# SCP to instance store of aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I have an instance of ec2 which has a root device and a instance store attached to it. When I scp to the root device then there is no problem, but when I scp to the instance store then it gives me permission denied error. 
The command I am using is following
scp -i/home/usmanmahmood/Desktop/abc/UsmanMahmood_KP.pem ~/Desktop/iozone3_414.tar ubuntu@ec2-54-224-70-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/mnt

The error which comes is 
scp: /mnt/iozone3_414.tar: Permission denied.

Can you tell me what the problem is, and is the instance storage is on mnt ? I am doing mnt because when I do "df -h" after loging in to the ec2 by ssh I get the following output

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  876M  6.7G  12% / 
udev            819M   12K  819M   1% /dev 
tmpfs           331M  168K  331M   1% /run 
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock 
none            827M     0  827M   0% /run/shm 
/dev/xvdb       147G  188M  140G   1% /mnt

From the last I think that the instance store is on /mnt
Help please

Comment: The user `ubuntu` probably has no access to `/mnt` You can either give the user access or upload to another directory before moving it to the instance store.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually scp to the instance store, its not persistent store device which is attached to it, please be aware of the fact that if you reboot or shut down the instance you may loss that data which is stored the instance store, so I dont suggest you to store any critical data in the /mnt/. Obviously you will not have any access.